# Returning RValueRef: warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary

Tags: c++

I have a function to move an int from a storage-ptr:

```
int&& MoveFromStorage(void const* p)
{
    return static_cast<int&&>(*static_cast<int*>(const_cast<void*>(p)));
}

int main()
{
    int i = 10;
    int&& iRValRef = MoveFromStorage(&i);
}
```

Compiling this function with MSVC 2017 leads to `warning C4172: returning address of local variable or temporary`. I do not get this warning with clang or gcc. I do not see where I am returning address of local variable or temporary. Is this a bug in MSVC?

**EDIT**

Maybe I give some more context: I write a std::variant myself and for the visit-function I write following code:

```
template<class AlternativeType>
inline AlternativeType _cast_to(void const* variant_storage)
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<AlternativeType>::type without_ref;
    return static_cast<AlternativeType>(*static_cast<without_ref*>(const_cast<void*>(variant_storage)));
}

template<class AlternativeType, class Visitor>
inline auto _visit_impl(Visitor&& vis, void const* variant_storage)
    -> decltype(std::forward<Visitor>(vis)(_cast_to<AlternativeType>(variant_storage)))
{
    return std::forward<Visitor>(vis)(_cast_to<AlternativeType>(variant_storage));
}
```

And then I use those functions by filling an array with:

```
FPtrType arr[] =  { _visit_impl<QualifiedCurrentType>... };
```

whereas QualifiedCurrentType the Ith type of the variant is with the constness and referenceness of the variant applied. I.e. if the variant is passed by r-value-ref, QualifiedCurrentType will be an RvalueRef to some other Type. And for those cases, _cast_to generates the warning.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Visual studio is right, `&&` in a return type is strange to see

Comment: What about https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move

Comment: Looks fine to me. Super-weird, but fine.

Comment: Do you really need to *move* an int?

Comment: As it is part of my variant-implementation I move whatever type the user instantiates the variant with

Answer (score 0):

I can't explain it, but following change helped me to fix the code:

```
template<class AlternativeType>
inline AlternativeType _cast_to(void const* variant_storage)
{
    typedef typename std::remove_reference<AlternativeType>::type without_ref;
    without_ref* typedPointer = static_cast<without_ref*>(const_cast<void*>(variant_storage));
    return static_cast<AlternativeType>(*typedPointer);
}
```

So the solution is to store some intermediate typedPointer before applying further castings.